# tunneling to server which is behind 2 secured servers

Tags: tunnel

I am connecting to my secure linux servers with the following procedure.

1) first I am connecting to one connecting machine (system A). from here I am connecting to another connected server (system B). from system B we have direct access to our secured servers.

Here I need to access one of my linux server web console like server.map.com:7777 port.

How can I access this server URL.

Please help me here..

Is there any way that I can setup these 2 connected servers in p